# iterate throught unordered list (nav)

Tags: jquery, iteration, event-listener, megamenu

I am working on a Mega Menu and using a unordered list to trigger a event to show the Mega Menu.
This is the HTML code for Nav Bar:

```
<div class="alpha omega grid_15" id="topNavLink">
    <ul id="navRollOver">
      <li><a href="#" title="SOCCER" target="_self" >SOCCER</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="TENNIS" target="_self" >TENNIS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="BASEBALL" target="_self" >BASEBALL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="BASKETBALL" target="_self" >BASKETBALL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="FOOTBALL" target="_self" >FOOTBALL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="GOLF" target="_self" >GOLF</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="RUGBY" target="_self" >RUGBY</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="HOCKEY" target="_self" >HOCKEY</a></li>   
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I am calling a div with class `subNavContainer`, css status is `display: none`;

This is what I want to do... I am planning to get the Array of all the `li` and target `> a` and listen to the mouse enter event to trigger the mega menu to `slideDown`.

I need help with Iterating through the `li` checking if it has `a` and based on the `mouseenter` on `a` I want to trigger an event to display the `megaMenu` using `slideDown`, and when the mouse moves to the `next()` `a`, I want to trigger the `slideUp` event.

Similarly if the mouseenters the `subNavContainer` it should remain on screen and when the mouseleaves the `subNavContainer` or if there is no movement on the screen the `subNavContainer` should `slideUp`.

Answer (score 0):

To select all the links that are children of the `li` elements your selector can look like this:

```
//select root element (`ul`), get its children (in this case the `li` elements), then get the children `a` elements of those `li` elements
$('#navRollOver').children().children('a')
```

To then bind to the `mouseenter` event for those elements:

```
//note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and is the same in this case as `.bind()`
$('#navRollOver').children().children('a').on('mouseenter', function () {
    //do slideDown
});
```

Then to `slideUp` the menu after the cursor leaves the link elements:

```
//you can chain function calls with jQuery functions,
//so we make our selection of the `a` elements, bind a `mouseenter` event handler to them,
//then using the same selection, we bind a `mouseleave` event handler
$('#navRollOver').children().children('a').on('mouseenter', function () {
    //do slideDown
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    //do slideUp
});
```

Comment: I tried this but the issue is that when I move my mouse away from the top nav to the .subNavContainer(megaMenu) it slidesUp as there is no condition to keep the status to visible or down when the mouse event changes from top nav to the subNavContainer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var lastHoveredItem = null, hoveredOnMegaMenu = false;
$("#navRollOver > li > a").mouseenter(function(){
    hoveredOnMegaMenu = false;
    var $this = $(this);
    if(lastHoveredItem != null){
       lastHoveredItem.slideUp();
    }
    //Now based on the menu hovered you can find its its associated mega menu container
    lastHoveredItem = $(".megaMenu" + $this.attr('title')).slideDown();
})
.mouseleave(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      if(!hoveredOnMegaMenu && lastHoveredItem){
          lastHoveredItem.slideUp();
          lastHoveredItem = null;
      }
   });
});

//You can give megaMenu class to each of the mega menu containers so that we can 
//easily select them with class selector
$(".megaMenu").mouseenter(function(){
    hoveredOnMegaMenu = true;
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).slideUp();
    lastHoveredItem = null;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I tried working with this but it does not seem to trigger the slideDown or slideUp. My megamenu div container has class name subNavContainer. I update this class in the megaMenu class but it does not trigger anything. You can check the page on [view page](http://cintero.com/sports-design/new/) here.